# ADFS OAuth2 Password-Grant for LDAP Users

Tags: oauth-2.0, ldap, adfs

We are using ADFS 4.0 (2016) with two "LocalClaimProviderTrusts" aka Attribute Stores.

One is an Active Directory and the other one is a LDAP (IPA) Server.

**For some usecases we use the non-interactive OAUTH2 Endpoint "/adfs/oauth2/token". Where "grant_type" is "password.**

The whole secret client approach is not useable for us, because we need the user claims in the jwt token.

And here we ran in a limitation: 
This endpoint only accepts AD Users. If we try to authenticate LDAP users with username and password against this endpoint, we get an error in the event log indicating that ADFS is only searching for users in the Active Directory.

**My Question:**
Is there any chance to recieve a JWT Token representing a LDAP User non-interactively?

Thanks!

-Dave